# function to check if data is on the database

Tags: php

I create a function to find all firstname and lastname in my database all I want if that data is already exist I just want to output, error message

my question is how to create a function to check if data is already exist?

this is my function to find all data of firstname and lastname.

```
function find_student_by_firstname($firstname){
  global $con;

  $safe_firstname = prep($firstname);

  $sql  = "SELECT * ";
  $sql .= "FROM studeprofile ";
  $sql .= "WHERE FirstName = '{$safe_firstname}' ";
  $sql .= "LIMIT 1";
  $student_set = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  confirm_query($student_set);
  if($student = mysqli_fetch_assoc($student_set)){
    return $student;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

function find_student_by_lastname($lastname){
  global $con;

  $safe_lastname = prep($lastname);

  $sql  = "SELECT * ";
  $sql .= "FROM studeprofile ";
  $sql .= "WHERE LastName = '{$safe_lastname}' ";
  $sql .= "LIMIT 1";
  $student_set = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  confirm_query($student_set);
  if($student = mysqli_fetch_assoc($student_set)){
    return $student;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

this is my current function to check if data is already exist.

```
function match_fistname_lastname($lastname, $firstname){
  $student_firstname = find_student_by_firstname($lastname);
  if($student_firstname){
    find_student_by_lastname($lastname);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: You do know about the `AND` operator for SELECT queries? Just SELECT those entries where the FirstName matches `AND` the LastName matches.

Comment: thank you, your suggestion help to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean by "data is already exist" that a person is in the database that matches to firstname and lastname, you don't have to execute two queries. 
Use the **`and`** in mysql like this:

```
function find_student($firstname, $lastname){
  global $con;

  $safe_firstname = prep($firstname);
  $safe_lastname = prep($lastname);

  $sql  = "SELECT * ";
  $sql .= "FROM studeprofile ";
  $sql .= "WHERE FirstName = '{$safe_firstname}' and LastName = '{$safe_lastname}' ";
  $sql .= "LIMIT 1";
  $student_set = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  confirm_query($student_set);
  if($student = mysqli_fetch_assoc($student_set)){
    return $student;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```